# Set up Cloudera CDH6.2 coding pySpark in hue's note book and run

Tags: pyspark, cloudera, hue

I have install cdh6.2 followed office documents, and it's running correctly. But I still want code pySpark and run it in hue instead of coding pySpark in pySpark-shell. I have tried a lot of configurations in CHD's hue Configuration page. what I have did like:

```
[notebook]

  [[interpreters]]

    [[[spark]]]
        name=Scala
        interface=livy
    [[[pyspark]]]
        name=PySpark
        interface=livy
    [[[r]]]
        name=R
        interface=livy
```

installed livy with version 0.6.0, livy server log:

```
19/05/09 18:01:25 INFO server.AccessManager: AccessControlManager acls disabled;users with view permission: ;users with modify permission: ;users with super permission: ;other allowed users: *
19/05/09 18:01:25 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: WARNING: User-defined SPARK_HOME (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-6.2.0-1.cdh6.2.0.p0.967373/lib/spark) overrides detected (/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark).
19/05/09 18:01:25 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: WARNING: Running spark-class from user-defined location.
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Welcome to
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:       ____              __
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:      / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:     _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:    /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.4.0-cdh6.2.0
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:       /_/
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream:                         
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Using Scala version 2.11.12, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_212
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Branch HEAD
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Compiled by user jenkins on 2019-03-14T07:01:24Z
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Revision HEAD
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Url 
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO utils.LineBufferedStream: Type --help for more information.
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO recovery.StateStore$: Using BlackholeStateStore for recovery.
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO sessions.BatchSessionManager: Recovered 0 batch sessions. Next session id: 0
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO sessions.InteractiveSessionManager: Recovered 0 interactive sessions. Next session id: 0
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO sessions.InteractiveSessionManager: Heartbeat watchdog thread started.
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @1490ms
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.3.24.v20180605, build timestamp: 2018-06-06T01:11:56+08:00, git hash: 84205aa28f11a4f31f2a3b86d1bba2cc8ab69827
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@1522d8a0{/,file:///opt/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/src/main/org/apache/livy/server,AVAILABLE}
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO server.AbstractNCSARequestLog: Opened /opt/apache-livy-0.6.0-incubating-bin/logs/2019_05_09.request.log
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@77a98a6a{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8998}
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO server.Server: Started @1674ms
19/05/09 18:01:26 INFO server.WebServer: Starting server on http://cdh.n1.com:8998
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see after adding:

```
[desktop]
app_blacklist=

[notebook]
  show_notebooks=true
```

Comment: I tried, but still not work, I find issue here is install and config hue by cdh, the information hue used to connect other components is offered by chd, but in my version of cdh6.2 there is no information to livy.

Comment: After setup livy and use hue config your mentioned. it works.